# Creating a new variable based on text field in dataset (results to be "0" or "1")

Tags: r

I'm working on an exercise to create a support vector machine, but am stuck at an early step.  The dataset I'm working with measures restaurant health violations, and may be found here: https://health.data.ny.gov/Health/Food-Service-Establishment-Last-Inspection/cnih-y5dw

This data has been imported into R-Studio.  I need to look at the VIOLATIONS variable, and create a variable (true/false, 0/1?), to be added to this dataset - which will be used later in the SVM potion.  After a quick inspection, restaurants with no violations seem to contain the text string "No violations found." in the VIOLATIONS variable.  So I'm thinking I need to setup a function to run through the thousands of records and compare entries against that text.

My guess is that I want to give restaurants with no violations a "0" or "FALSE" mark, whereas the restaurants with violations (any other text) would receive a "1" or "TRUE" mark.  This needs to be processed for every entry in the dataset, and the resulting values need to be added to this dataset as a new variable (for later analysis).

I'm hoping somebody can provide hints or suggestions (or just help) on how to go about this, so I can move onto the SVM!  Any ideas?

I wasn't sure the best way to ask this so didn't see any good examples when I tried searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called your `data.frame` `df` and the new added column `ANYVIOLATIONS`.

As far as I can see from a brief glance at the provided data `VIOLATIONS` always exactly matches "No violations found." if there were no violations. Thus the code to get a logical vector that meets your requirements should be quite simple:

```
df$ANYVIOLATIONS <- df$VIOLATIONS != "No violations found."
```

Comment: And if your text is more generic, you could do it with a regular expression, for example if you're trying to find all things like "No violations founds.", "No problems found.", etc., you could use ```df$new_column <- !grepl("no .* found", df$VIOLATIONS, ignore.case = T)```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I now need to convert "TRUE" and "FALSE" to "1" and "0", respectively.  Fortunately, I was able to figure that part out on my own!  For anyone curious, you can do this: df$ANYVIOLATIONS[df$ANYVIOLATIONS == "FALSE"] <- "0" and so on.  Thanks again, guys.

Comment: @wici how would you change the above?  I did convert to "1" and "0", if you see my above comment.  Will that not accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @user3491754 well I would type ´df$ANYVIOLATIONS <- as.numeric(df$VIOLATIONS != "No violations found.")´. Sorry I had a misspelling in my comment, but couldn't edit it. I'm not sure how you implemented your code but you wrote ´<- "0"´ which would be a string and I doubt you'd want that.