# Create vectors containing 0 or 1 based on subjects in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I've got the following `data.frame`

```
ARTICLE   <- c("I'M ARTICLE #1","I'M ARTICLE #2","I'M ARTICLE #3","I'M ARTICLE #4")
SUBJECT.1 <- c("POLLUTION", "ACQUIRED", "INSIDER TRADING", "MERGERS & ACQUISITIONS")
SUBJECT.2 <- c("FRAUD", "POLLUTION & DAMAGES", "FRAUD & INSIDER TRADING", "OIL SPILLS")
SUBJECT.3 <- c("OIL", "BIOFUELS", "OIL SPILLS & WASTE", "EMISSIONS")

mydf <- data.frame(ARTICLE, SUBJECT.1, SUBJECT.2, SUBJECT.3)
mydf

#          ARTICLE              SUBJECT.1               SUBJECT.2          SUBJECT.3
# 1 I'M ARTICLE #1              POLLUTION                   FRAUD                OIL
# 2 I'M ARTICLE #2               ACQUIRED     POLLUTION & DAMAGES           BIOFUELS
# 3 I'M ARTICLE #3        INSIDER TRADING FRAUD & INSIDER TRADING OIL SPILLS & WASTE
# 4 I'M ARTICLE #4 MERGERS & ACQUISITIONS              OIL SPILLS          EMISSIONS
```

I want to group some of the subjects and create columns for dummy variables. I want 4 columns named `POLLUTION, OILSPILLS, MERGERS and FRAUD`. There should be a 1 in this column, only if certain words or parts of words appear in the three SUBJECT columns:

```
# POLLUTION: if the words "POLLUTION", "EMISSION", "WASTE" appear in one or more of the columns
# OILSPILLS: if the word "OIL SPILL" appears in one or more of the columns
# MERGERS: if the words "MERGER", "ACQUI" appear in one or more of the columns
# FRAUD: if the words "FRAUD", "CRIME" appear in one or more of the columns
```

The output should look like this:

```
#          ARTICLE              SUBJECT.1               SUBJECT.2          SUBJECT.3 POLLUTION OILSPILLS MERGERS FRAUD
# 1 I'M ARTICLE #1              POLLUTION                   FRAUD                OIL         1         0       0     1
# 2 I'M ARTICLE #2               ACQUIRED     POLLUTION & DAMAGES           BIOFUELS         1         0       1     0
# 3 I'M ARTICLE #3        INSIDER TRADING FRAUD & INSIDER TRADING OIL SPILLS & WASTE         1         1       0     1
# 4 I'M ARTICLE #4 MERGERS & ACQUISITIONS               OILSPILLS          EMISSIONS         1         1       1     0
```

Since I have no Idea on how to do that, I couldn't really try anything.

Thank you!

Comment: "*Since I have no Idea on how to do that, I couldn't really try anything.*" It's funny then that entering the exact subject of your question in the 'Ask question' box suggests this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122771/creating-a-new-variable-based-on-text-field-in-dataset-results-to-be-0-or-1 as a "Question that may already have your answer", which would have pointed you to `grepl`. Effort is appreciated.

Comment: @ thelatemail: I tend to forget about that search function, because it didn't really work for me in the past. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t(  apply(mydf[-1], 1, function(x)  as.numeric ( c(   
   # need the t() to change columns to rows
 any( grepl("POLLUTION|EMISSION|WASTE", x) ),
 any(grepl("OIL\\sSPILL", x) ), 
 any(grepl("MERGER|ACQUI", x) ), 
 any(grepl("MERGER|ACQUI", x) )      )
       )     )
 )
 #-------
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    1

 cbind(mydf, .Last.value)
     ARTICLE              SUBJECT.1               SUBJECT.2
1 I'M ARTICLE #1              POLLUTION                   FRAUD
2 I'M ARTICLE #2               ACQUIRED     POLLUTION & DAMAGES
3 I'M ARTICLE #3        INSIDER TRADING FRAUD & INSIDER TRADING
4 I'M ARTICLE #4 MERGERS & ACQUISITIONS              OIL SPILLS
           SUBJECT.3 1 2 3 4
1                OIL 1 0 0 0
2           BIOFUELS 1 0 1 1
3 OIL SPILLS & WASTE 1 1 0 0
4          EMISSIONS 1 1 1 1
```

There are probably more elegant methods, but this seemed sufficiently "obvious" that this bear of little brain could put it down on "paper". The naming of the columns seems sufficiently trivial that it can be left as "an exercise for the reader".

Answer (score 3):

Slightly modified from "BondedDust's" answer

```
vec1 <- c(POLLUTION="POLLUTION|EMISSION|WASTE", OILSPILLS="OIL SPILL",
        MERGERS="MERGER|ACQUI", FRAUD="FRAUD|CRIME")

sapply(vec1, function(x) apply(mydf[,-1],1, function(y) any(grepl(x, y))))+0
cbind(mydf, .Last.value)
```