# replace Logical,0 with 0

Tags: r, matrix

I attempted to answer this question: [Create vectors containing 0 or 1 based on subjects in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338396/create-vectors-containing-0-or-1-based-on-subjects-in-r)
I only got as far as the following line of code, which returns a `matrix` named `pollution`:

```
pollution <- apply(mydf[,2:4], c(1,2), function(i) {  
                   ifelse(grep('POLLUTION|EMISSION|WASTE',i)==1,1,0)} )
pollution

#      SUBJECT.1 SUBJECT.2 SUBJECT.3
# [1,] 1         Logical,0 Logical,0
# [2,] Logical,0 1         Logical,0
# [3,] Logical,0 Logical,0 1        
# [4,] Logical,0 Logical,0 1
```

Assuming I started with the `matrix` `pollution`, how can I convert it to a `matrix` 
of `1`'s and `0`'s:

```
#      SUBJECT.1 SUBJECT.2 SUBJECT.3
# [1,] 1         0         0
# [2,] 0         1         0
# [3,] 0         0         1        
# [4,] 0         0         1
```

I have answered several questions on Stack Overflow regarding how to replace `NA`'s with `0`'s, etc.  However, I cannot figure out how to replace these `Logical,0`'s.

For example:

```
pollution[is.logical(pollution)] = 0

#      SUBJECT.1 SUBJECT.2 SUBJECT.3
# [1,] 1         Logical,0 Logical,0
# [2,] Logical,0 1         Logical,0
# [3,] Logical,0 Logical,0 1        
# [4,] Logical,0 Logical,0 1

pollution2 <- as.data.frame(pollution)
pollution2

#   SUBJECT.1 SUBJECT.2 SUBJECT.3
# 1         1                    
# 2                   1          
# 3                             1
# 4                             1
```

Thank you for any advice.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.  Searching for the word `logical` returns a lot of hits.

Comment: Zero-length vectors can be separated by condition `length(v)>0`, but I think there should exist a small tweak to your `apply` that returns the correct matrix.

Comment: @tonytonov Thank you for the reply.  I am not sure I understand the first part.  As for the `apply`, I want to pretend it does not exist and just start with the `matrix` pollution.

Comment: I think the difficulty is that your matrix, (the result of your apply) does not have a nice structure; they are list elements, hence the normal replacement methods do not work. Look at `str(pollution)` and `class(pollution[2])` for example.  Perhaps, `sapply(mydf[-1], function(i)           grepl('POLLUTION|EMISSION|WASTE',i) ) *1` avoids this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this also helps:

```
 matrix(sapply(c(pollution),length),4)
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1
```

or

```
matrix((!sapply(pollution, is.logical))+0,4)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest I can think of:

```
pollution2 <- pollution
pollution2[] <- as.numeric(sapply(pollution, function(x) length(x) > 0))
pollution2
     SUBJECT.1 SUBJECT.2 SUBJECT.3
[1,] 1         0         0        
[2,] 0         1         0        
[3,] 0         0         1        
[4,] 0         0         1
```

Note how I preserve the matrix structure and dimnames by using `[]` notation.

EDIT: The tweak to `apply` is quite simple, just FYI

```
apply(mydf[,2:4], c(1,2), function(i) {  
  ifelse(length(grep('POLLUTION|EMISSION|WASTE',i)),1,0)} )
     SUBJECT.1 SUBJECT.2 SUBJECT.3
[1,]         1         0         0
[2,]         0         1         0
[3,]         0         0         1
[4,]         0         0         1
```

Comment: Your `apply` statement is very helpful.  I just realized `grep` does not seem to return `FALSE` and using `length` appears to be a way to obtain a `FALSE` or `0` with it.

Answer (score 2):

I know I can do this:

```
> new.pollution <- matrix(as.numeric(pollution), nrow=4, byrow=FALSE)
> new.pollution[is.na(new.pollution)] = 0
> new.pollution
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1
```

But surely there is an easier way.